# How to align left and right text mat-card-header in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, alignment, angular-material, mat-card

I need to align the text content in the header on left and right side of header tag. i tried different ideas, but none works for me. help me.

```
 <div style="width: 40%">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header class="card-container">
      <mat-card-title class="card-container-right"> Test right</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-title class="card-container-left"> Test left</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: use of <p>,<div>,<span> with style of textallign:left , right etc @Narm

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this if you want to continue to use the `mat-title` elements:

See working [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5njbxh)

**In your (I'll call it) example-card.component.html file**

```
<mat-card  >
<mat-card-header>
 <mat-card-title class="card-container-left"> Test left</mat-card-title>
 <mat-card-title class="card-container-right"> Test right</mat-card- title>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-content>
</mat-card-content>
```

Then in your **example-card.component.css**

```
.card-container-right{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

.card-container-left{
  display: inline;
}
```

..and finally in your **styles.css**

```
.mat-card-header-text{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

The trick to this is overriding Angular materials `.mat-card-header-text` to be 100% the width of the `mat-card-header`. Otherwise it behaves like in inline element and only takes up the width of its children elements text. Preventing you from spacing them out.

Comment: i was trying my own solution, no need to downvote! downvote is for wrong answer.

Comment: Hi @fatemefazli, it wasn't me that downvoted your answer. Although I did just look at your demo and it doesn't work btw.

Comment: This is not working with the current version. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can use what material design uses in mat-toolbar

```
<mat-card-title>
   <span>Test left</span>
   <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
   <span>Test right</span>
</mat-card-title>
```

in your .css

```
.fill-remaining-space {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

I am sorry, This doesn't work !!!!! Works in Mat-Toolbar, bat not in Mat-card Title.

Here is how it works, I knew I had used it somewhere

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title-group>
    <span>Test left</span>
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <span>Test right</span>
  </mat-card-title-group>
</mat-card>
```

see : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu for working example

Comment: Worked for me in `mat-card-header` 

Answer (score 4):

add custom css on **.mat-card-header** class

```
 .mat-card-header{
        justify-content: flex-end /* for right*/
        justify-content: flex-start /* for left*/
        justify-content: centre /* for center*/

    }
```