# How to set groups of elements to the left and to the right inside the mat-card-header?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I need to set groups of header elements to the left and to the right.

I have something like that:

```
<mat-card-header>

      <div fxLayout="row">

        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div>Alex Isakau</div>
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/alexisakau">
            <img alt="tw" src="../../assets/img/twitter.png" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexisakau/">
            <img alt="in" src="../../assets/img/linked.png" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div>about</div>
          <div>portfolio</div>
          <div>contact</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </mat-card-header>
```

And CSS that's relative to the mat-card-header:

```
.mat-card {
   padding: 0;
}

.mat-card-header {
  background-color: rgb(42, 5, 128);
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 5px 25px;
}
```

[image: img]

After adding fxLayoutGap:

```
<mat-card-header>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="120%">
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Like I said, it is not responsive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align left and right text mat-card-header in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008662/how-to-align-left-and-right-text-mat-card-header-in-angular-4)

Comment: Please also share the css. You need to provide a minimum verifiable example so we can reproduce your problem. Please do it before people start giving thumbs-down.Just trying to help :)

Comment: No, that solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Just now I set fxLayoutGap="155%" property and it seems like it works for me, but maybe you guys know something better? <mat-card-header>

      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="155%">, but.. it is not responsive in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either do it by making your wrapper div fxLayoutAlign 'space-between'

```
   <mat-card-header>
     <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="1 0 0" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <div>Alex Isakau</div>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/alexisakau">
                <img alt="tw" src="../../assets/img/twitter.png" width="40" height="40">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexisakau/">
               <img alt="in" src="../../assets/img/linked.png" width="40" height="40">
            </a>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <div>about</div>
        <div>portfolio</div>
        <div>contact</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
```

or

giving `margin-left: auto` to the div you want to move right

```
   <mat-card-header>
     <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="1 0 0">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <div>Alex Isakau</div>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/alexisakau">
                <img alt="tw" src="../../assets/img/twitter.png" width="40" height="40">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexisakau/">
               <img alt="in" src="../../assets/img/linked.png" width="40" height="40">
            </a>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="11px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="margin-left:auto">
        <div>about</div>
        <div>portfolio</div>
        <div>contact</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
```

and in both cases make wrapper div `flex-grow: 1` by providing `fxFlex="1 0 0"`

Comment: This is awesome!